# Inserting an optional word wrapping point using CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to format a quotation that has a reference at the end. My markup looks like this:

```
<p class=quotation>
    "Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's life.
    Don't be trapped by dogma – which is living with the results of 
    other people's thinking."<span class=reference>Steve Jobs</span>
</p>
```

I am inserting an em-dash before the `span` using the CSS `::before` pseudo-element. However, the line breaks are a bit ugly. I would prefer to have no line breaks within the quotation itself, so my CSS currently looks like this:

```
.quotation .reference::before {
    content: '—';
}
.quotation .reference {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Unfortunately, this means that the last word (in this case, `thinking.") gets attached to the em-dash and breaks to the new line as well.

I want two things to happen:

- when the reference fits on the same line as the end of the quotation, there should be no space before the dash
- when the reference does not fit, the wrapping should be done before the em-dash

I have tried inserting a zero-width space with `content: '\200B—';`, but this seems to have no effect at all.

Is there any way of achieving this in pure CSS?

In this snippet, the `div` is resizable so you can see how the line break is not inserted.

```css
.quotation .reference::before {
  content: '—';
}
.quotation .reference {
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/* make div resizable to see the effect */

div {
  resize: both;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class=quotation>
    "Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's life. Don't be trapped by dogma – which is living with the results of other people's thinking."<span class=reference>Steve Jobs</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: "gets attached to the em-dash and breaks to the new line as well" -> Not on firefox, actually (all is fine here)

Comment: @Kaddath That's interesting. Unfortunately I'm targeting Chrome! (My tooling involves Puppeteer, so I'm more interested than normal in quite tight control over layout.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make it `inline-block` to avoid the *gets attached* effect:

```css
.quotation .reference::before {
  content: '—';
}
.quotation .reference {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
}


/* make div resizable to see the effect */

div {
  resize: both;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class=quotation>
    "Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's life. Don't be trapped by dogma – which is living with the results of other people's thinking."<span class=reference>Steve Jobs</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is working exactly the same as the code in my question.

Comment: @lonesomeday so I guess we need more details about you system and browser version ... my code doesn't behave the same as yours (using Chrome last version on a Windows system)

Comment: @lonesomeday check again the update, moved the inline-block to the parent element, should be the same behavior